# Android webview pull to refresh issue with bootstrap modal

Tags: android, webview, bootstrap-modal

I have an issue with an android app using a webview. I have wrapped the webview inside a swiperefreshlayout:

```xml
    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

When the refresh is triggered the webview gets reloaded. This works perfect most of the times for me. The issue I have is when the webpage is scrolled to the top, and a modal that is higher than the webview is opened. When scrolling down in the modal everything is working fine, but when trying to scroll up the issue happens. The drag to refresh gets triggered. As far as I can see it is because the webpage behind the modal is scrolled to the top, it thinks it should refresh.

Does anyone know how to get around this issue?

Comment: I know this is old, but did you figure it out? Same issue.

Comment: I was using bootstrap and had the on open and on the close event for the modal. Then I just forwarded the event through JavaScript channels and disabled/enabled the pull to refresh. There is most likely a better way of doing it, but that was what I ended up doing due to time

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable pull to refresh when webview scroll Y is not 0. Please check the code below:

```
    pullToRefresh.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {
            if (webView.getScrollY() == 0)
                pullToRefresh.setEnabled(true);
            else
                pullToRefresh.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
```

Using this you will not see the issue while scrolling to top in webview.

Comment: That was not the issue. The webpage is scrolled to the top and webView.getScrollY() == 0, but I have a bootstrap modal that is longer than the height of the webview, giving me a scrollbar. But when I try to scroll back up in the modal it triggers the refresh call

Comment: plz send that link i will try in webview to look deep into it.